# Add xml namespace to xml_document using pugixml

Tags: c++, pugixml

How can I add an `xml namespace` declaration to my `xml_document` using pugixml?

I tried this, which results in a invalid xml (invalid char ":", says my validator):

```
xml_document doc;

auto declarationNode = doc.append_child(node_declaration);

declarationNode.append_attribute("xmlns\:xsi") = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
```

I guess a namespace declaration is not the same as an xml attribute.

**But how can I add that namespace declaration?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quoting *zeux*, the creator of pugixml, who was so kind to answer this question [here on github](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml/issues/354)

> This code appends the xmlns attribute to the  node; you should
>   append it to the document element instead:

```
doc.document_element().append_attribute("xmlns:xsi") = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
```

> The code I noted adds the attribute to “rootnode” element and as such
>   must be ran after you add rootnode to the document.